# How to ssh without password and using a different user name?

Tags: ssh, password

I know for the same user name, we can do:

1. ssh-keygen
2. ssh-copy-id

to skip entering the password.

However, in my understanding, this is for remote and client servers both having the same user name.

However, the user name in the remote server didn't exist in my client server. How can I do `ssh-copy-id` here to skip entering the password?

ex: I need to do as follows:

```
mark@client:~$ ssh jack@ip_of_remote_server
```

Comment: If you've ever used public-key authentication with GitHub, you might have noticed that *everyone* logs in with the same user ID, `git`. That user happens to have millions of different public keys associated with it, and the key used determines which GitHub account you get access to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no obligation to have the same user name on the remote machine.

- Your username on the local machine is `jack`
- Your username on the remote machine is `john`
- you can append `john@<remote IP>` to all your commands.

So:

1. `ssh-keygen`. This is a local operation, it remains unchanged.
2. `ssh-copy-id john@<remote IP>`. This copies the private key of `jack@local` to the authorized keys of `john@remote`.
3. `ssh john@remote` will log you in.

### Note on default values

When you run `ssh remote`, the program defaults to using the username of your local user. So it's really equivalent to `ssh jack@remote`

Comment: Additionally you can set the user in the ssh config, eg: `echo -e 'Host <remote IP>\n\tUser john' >> .ssh/config`